# Test Azure application in Dev Fabric

Tags: azure, cloud

I have a created a sample web role application using cloud service. Before hosting my application in cloud, i want to test the application in Dev Fabric. I am sure that when we run the application from VS, it creates an environment that simulates the cloud.

But, if I want to give my application for testing to QA, do I still need to give my source to them and run the application from VS under Dev Fabric or is there any other ways in running my deployed package under Dev Fabric.

In a line, my question is: How do i run my packaged Azure application under Dev Fabric before hosting in Cloud?

Can anyone having an idea, please share me some information?

---

Thanks for your quick response. CSRun command helped in accoomplishing my requirement. But i can see that it is taking an IP Address, `http://127.0.0.1:80/` by default.

Also i am trying to find it out that, is there a way we can change this to a proper name instead of using like an IP? 
for ex: `http://localhost/` or 
with deployed machine name like `http://applicationserver/webrole1/` - so that we can access this from any machine in the netwrok.

I went through the Dev Fabric UI, where we can see the curent instances running, but i didnt find any options for these.

Please share me some information on this.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your application locally, a different kind of package gets created (actually a directory) with a .csx extension.

As long as you have that .csx directory and your configuration file (.cscfg), you can run the package by using the "csrun" command.  (So no, you don't need Visual Studio.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. CSRun command helped in accoomplishing my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this blog post to access azure services running in DevFabric (DF) from other boxes - 
http://blog.ehuna.org/2009/10/an_easier_way_to_access_the_wi.html